# How to sync External Secrets on an AKS Cluster with an Azure Key Vault?

Tags: kubernetes, azure, azure-kubernetes-service, secret-management

I'm trying to integrate AKS with Key Vault using the [External Secrets](https://external-secrets.io) operator. I've set up the operator itself using the Helm chart, and I've created a `SecretStore` resource pointed at a Vault (we'll call it `keyvault-demo`). However, when I attempt to create `ExternalSecret` resources, the status says `SecretSyncedError` and provides no meaningful error beyond "`could not get secret data from provider`".

Here's the YAML for both the `SecretStore` and the `ExternalSecret`:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: SecretStore
metadata:
  name: azure-backend
spec:
  provider:
    azurekv:
      tenantId: <REDACTED>
      vaultUrl: "https://<redacted>.vault.azure.net/"
      authType: ServicePrincipal
      authSecretRef:
        clientId:
          name: azure-secret-sp
          key: ClientID
        clientSecret:
          name: azure-secret-sp
          key: ClientSecret
```

```yaml
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: azure-example
spec:
  refreshInterval: 15m
  secretStoreRef:
    kind: SecretStore
    name: azure-backend
  target:
    name: azure-secret
  data:
  - secretKey: foobar
    remoteRef:
      key: secret/example-externalsecret-key
```

I've verified that the names of the Key Vault, the Service Principal, and the secret within the Vault are all correct. What am I missing?